# Linq to SQL stored procedure and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is being called in Linq-to-Sql to return Multiple Results.  Defined like this

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.FillProfileProductData")]
        [ResultType(typeof(spFillShoppingTabResult1))]
        [ResultType(typeof(spFillShoppingTabResult2))]
        [ResultType(typeof(spFillShoppingTabResult3))]
        public IMultipleResults FillProfileProductData([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "UserId", DbType = "BigInt")] System.Nullable<long> userId)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), userId);
            return (IMultipleResults)result.ReturnValue;
        }
```

Now, when I make `spFillShoppingTabResult1` inherit from `spFillShoppingTabResult2` it does not work at all.  But when none of these objects are inheriting from each other , it works fine.

Error I get is

> Data member 'Int32 ProgramID' of type 'spFillShoppingTabResult2' is not part of the
>   mapping for type 'spFillShoppingTabResult1'. Is the member above the root of an
>   inheritance hierarchy?